# Android : System Clock update from GPS in case, no other time source is present and NITZ is not supported

Tags: android, gps

I have a requirement where I don't have internet & NITZ support for my target board.  GPS Antenna is connected, and I am able to get the location update.

I have implemented my own GPS HAL, I would like to know if AOSP (LocationManager) automatically update the System Clock based on data received from GPS Provider.  I can see that it is not updating in my target. Do I need to implement any extra callback?

Or I can write java application where I receive the location update, and I have to update system clock based on location fix ( I mean LocationManager does not support automatic updates in Android if we have only GPS as the time source ?)

Comment: AOSP does not support update time from GPS source. You need to implement the mechanism by yourself.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I have implemented my own mechanism to update system time  recently and it works fine